# React useRef / forwardRef not working as expected when focusing a radio button

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, react-forwardref

I've put together a little demo here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-meitner-r3wzq?file=/src/App.js

When I click the button to display and focus on my first radio button - My radio styling isn't applied.  Although, if you press space immediately after, it focuses the right element.

The strange thing is, if I focus after a 1ms timeout, it works as expected.  Obviously this is more of a hack than a solution...

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here, any help would be great!

Thanks!!

Alternatively - This is all of the code required to replicate:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const { useRef, forwardRef, useState } = React;

const Button = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Click me to show and focus radio buttons</button>
);

const Fieldset = styled.fieldset`
  display: ${props => (props.isVisible ? "block" : "none")};

  input {
    :focus {
      outline: 5px solid red;
    }
  }
`;

const RadioButtons = forwardRef(({ isVisible, legend }, ref) => (
  <Fieldset isVisible={isVisible}>
    <legend>{legend}</legend>
    <label for="one">One</label>
    <input ref={ref} type="radio" id="one" name="radios" />
    <label for="two">Two</label>
    <input type="radio" id="two" name="radios" />
  </Fieldset>
));

export default function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const focusInput = () => {
    setIsVisible(true);

    // This doesn't work as expected
    inputRef.current.focus();

    // This does - But it definitely doesn't feel like a "solution"
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   inputRef.current.focus();
    // }, 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={focusInput} />
      <RadioButtons
        isVisible={isVisible}
        ref={inputRef}
        legend="Radio Legend"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the focusing login inside the `useEffect` hook like this

```
export default function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const focusInput = () => {
    setIsVisible(true);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isVisible]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={focusInput} />
      <RadioButtons
        isVisible={isVisible}
        ref={inputRef}
        legend="Radio Legend"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-roentgen-8ji2o?file=/src/App.js:745-1206)

Comment: Haha but it seems you find the solution yourself so the answer didn't make much sense :)

Comment: I got there by luck!  I still appreciate the help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As it always seems to go...  You feel like you exhaust every option - Then you write a question, and then you immediately find the answer!

In this instance - Moving the refs focus into a `useEffect` that watches `isVisible` did the trick

```
useEffect(() => {
    // I check here because my actual code toggles isVisible 
    if (isVisible) inputRef.current.focus();
}, [isVisible]);
```

Still interested to see if this can be done in a better way though